# Passing environment variables to Managed VM instances

Tags: google-app-engine, managed-vm

How can I pass environment variables to Managed VM instances on Google App Engine? Is it possible?

Comment: have you looked at metadata service?

Comment: I saw it, but it requires special coding to get some values and so it is not what I want. I am looking for something like the [one for Python App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables)

Comment: do you start the instances from appengine?

Comment: I started my Docker container as an App Engine Managed VM instance for evaluation. I can make a Dockerfile customized for App Engine but I would like to be able to reuse an existing Dockerfile and to change sensible application settings without redeploying a new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 places you can set Environmental Variables for Managed VM instances:

- [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables)
- [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#env)

That is the order of precedence as well.

Now it sounds like you already have a Dockerfile and you don't want to alter it to run in Managed VM's. But you will have to **add** a app.yaml to get your setup to work with Managed VM's, so add your environmental variables to your app.yaml like so:

```
env_variables:
  TESTENV: 'setinappyaml
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Since Managed VMs documentation is not clear about setting environment variables in app.yaml, I thought it was not implemented yet as they must be passed to `docker run`. I will try it.

Comment: I tested env_variables in app.yaml and it appeared to work. Is looks just missing from the Managed VMs documentation.

Comment: Does this work when running locally? For example, in python if I start my web server `gunicorn -b :8080 main:app` this isn't reading app.yaml so Im not getting the env_variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running completely locally it won't work. You have to run via the sdk, otherwise the app.yaml isn't even part of the equation.